# how to call matlab function in python script?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

All my previous work (some big functions) are programmed by Matlab (some .m files). Now I get some robots of which the embedded functions are programmed by python. I want to apply my Matlab functions into the robots, but it will be very hard to recode the functions by python. I find two methods:

1. call matlab function in python script: it need the Matlab environment, but the robot is independent of my PC when it works. I can not install Matlab in the robot.
2. translate matlab to python. I installed numpy and scipy, and tried to configure the tool SMOP (under Win7), but there is always an import error: no module named readline.

Another possibility is to write an interface with C to call the .M function, and another interface of C called by python, and then link these two interfaces. But I have no idea with this work.

So I can not continue my work. Can you give me some advice? thank you.

Comment: What kind of computer/OS is available to run the code? Is this some kind of standard PC which is capable of running the matlab runtime? (http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/)

Comment: have you looked into oct2py?

Comment: Can you put Octave on those machines?

Comment: You can generate standalone executable through the deploytool of matlab. In this way you can call the executable from python. Other way use matlab.engine for python, but it requires the matlab installed on your robot (it is not a good solution).